# GKImagePicker for swift project

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

My project is using
[GKImagePicker](https://github.com/gekitz/GKImagePicker)
as a plugin for croping image

But i can't find out how to implement it with my camera

Does someone know how to use [GKImagePicker](https://github.com/sachinkesiraju/SwiftExample) with camera for swift project?

Comment: according to classes which are available in 'GkImagePicker',It has 'CameraViewController' class.so you just need to present this controller to use camera

Comment: @AkashShinde hey! i didnt find it in that lib 
Do you have any example?

Comment: that controller is in their gitub page

Comment: hmm where is it on that gitub page i didn't find it